# error with tikz (bounding box) on ubuntu

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors

I created a latex beamer presentation on my Mac OSX and there
I included some pictures using tikz. Due to my job I migrated
to Ubuntu and now I want to use that presentation with Texmaker
(Latex via sudo apt-get install texlive-full).
Strangely now I get an error when I want to run Latex on my .tex file:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/title_minnow.png (no
BoundingBox).
```

For me this is very strange as the code works on my Mac with out problems.
What do I need to change, or do I need some extra installatoin etc.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (img1) at (current page.south west) 
        {\includegraphics[width = 3.5 cm, height=2.5cm]{images/title_minnow.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you just do `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=2.5cm]{images/title_minnow.png}\end{document}`?

Comment: Are you sure that you're processing the file with `pdflatex` on the Ubuntu system? TeXShop automatically uses it; the tool you're using on Ubuntu might be set to use `latex` (in DVI mode, that is, which can't include PNG files).

Comment: Had this same problem, only to realize that some how I was no longer processing with pdflatex.